# SD Card on Circuitpython, Adafruit Feather M0

Tags: python, adafruit, adafruit-circuitpython

I am attempting to run the following code as a prelude to writing data to an SD card on an Adafruit Feather M0 Adalogger using Thonny as my IDE.  According to https://github.com/adafruit/circuitpython/issues/317, the Adalogger did not always have SD card support, but that was patched in late 2017 and I've installed the most recent version of Circuitpython (8.2.2) on the Feather.  I'm following this group's (https://festorage.blob.core.windows.net/nasatechrise/files/nasatechrise-sensor-how-to.pdf) tutorial on how to access the SD card.

However, if I run the whole code, the device disconnects.  This makes me think it is a "me" problem, rather than a "them" issue.  To check, I cut down the code to just the SPI setup required to talk with the SD card.

```
import time
import board
import busio
import adafruit_sdcard
import storage
from digitalio import DigitalInOut

# initialize the I2c bus
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)

# initialize SPI bus and set CS pin
spi = busio.SPI(board.SCK, MOSI=board.MOSI, MISO=board.MISO)
# sd card reader CS pin on Feather M0 Adalogger is connected to board.D4
cs = DigitalInOut(board.D4)

# initialize sdcard and storage
sdcard = adafruit_sdcard.SDCard(spi, cs)
vfs = storage.VfsFat(sdcard)
# mount the storage device
storage.mount(vfs, "/sd")
```

Upon running this code snippet, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR   thonny.plugins.micropython.backend: PROBLEM WITH THONNY'S BACK-END:1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\plugins\micropython\backend.py", line 347, in _handle_normal_command
    response = handler(cmd)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\plugins\micropython\backend.py", line 695, in _cmd_execute_source
    self._execute(source, capture_output=False)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\plugins\micropython\backend.py", line 565, in _execute
    self._execute_with_consumer(script, self._send_output)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\plugins\micropython\bare_metal_backend.py", line 700, in _execute_with_consumer
    self._forward_output_until_active_prompt(output_consumer)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\plugins\micropython\bare_metal_backend.py", line 782, in _forward_output_until_active_prompt
    self._check_for_side_commands()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\plugins\micropython\backend.py", line 660, in _check_for_side_commands
    self._submit_input(cmd.data)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\plugins\micropython\backend.py", line 519, in _submit_input
    self._write(block)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\plugins\micropython\bare_metal_backend.py", line 533, in _write
    self._connection.write(data)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\plugins\micropython\serial_connection.py", line 85, in write
    assert size == len(data)
AssertionError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\plugins\micropython\backend.py", line 347, in _handle_normal_command
    response = handler(cmd)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\plugins\micropython\backend.py", line 695, in _cmd_execute_source
    self._execute(source, capture_output=False)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\plugins\micropython\backend.py", line 565, in _execute
    self._execute_with_consumer(script, self._send_output)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\plugins\micropython\bare_metal_backend.py", line 700, in _execute_with_consumer
    self._forward_output_until_active_prompt(output_consumer)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\plugins\micropython\bare_metal_backend.py", line 782, in _forward_output_until_active_prompt
    self._check_for_side_commands()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\plugins\micropython\backend.py", line 660, in _check_for_side_commands
    self._submit_input(cmd.data)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\plugins\micropython\backend.py", line 519, in _submit_input
    self._write(block)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\plugins\micropython\bare_metal_backend.py", line 533, in _write
    self._connection.write(data)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\plugins\micropython\serial_connection.py", line 85, in write
    assert size == len(data)
AssertionError
```

**UPDATE**

I truncated the code again, and now it gives me the following error while attempting the run the following code:

```
import time
import board
import busio
import adafruit_sdcard
import storage
from digitalio import DigitalInOut

spi = busio.SPI(board.SCK,MOSI=board.MOSI, MISO=board.MISO)
cs = DigitalInOut(board.D4)
print("SPI set up")
sdcard = adafruit_sdcard.SDCard(spi,cs)
print("SD card defined")
vfs = storage.VfsFat(sdcard)
```

Error (after 3-5 minutes):

```
Connection lost (EOF)

Use Stop/Restart to reconnect.
```